# NLog - How to add comma after each loging JSON document?

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, nlog

Using NLog, how to add a comma after each Json message like this?

```
{ "time": "2022-10-12", "name": "Index", "level": "ERROR", "message": "Hello Logging" }

,  <-----

{ "time": "2022-10-12", "name": "Index", "level": "ERROR", "message": "Hello Logging" }
```

**Here is nlog.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true"
      internalLogLevel="Error"
      internalLogFile="c:\\LogFiles\TasksInternalLog.txt">

    <!-- enable asp.net core layout renderers -->
    <extensions>
            <add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore"/>
    </extensions>


    <variable name="newDoc" value=","/>
    
    <targets>
        <target xsi:type="File" name="tasksJsonFile" fileName="c:\\logFiles\\json-${shortdate}.log">

            <layout xsi:type="JsonLayout" includeAllProperties="false">
                <attribute name="time" layout="${longdate}" />
                <attribute name="name" layout="${callsite}" />
                <attribute name="level" layout="${level:upperCase=true}"/>
                <attribute name="message" layout="${message}" />
                <!--<layout xsi:type="TextLayout" includeAllProperties="false" delimiter="Comma" withHeader="false">
                    ${newDoc}
                </layout>-->
            </layout>
            <layout xsi:type="TextLayout" includeAllProperties="false" delimiter="Comma" withHeader="false">
                
                ,
            </layout>

        </target>


    </targets>

    <rules>
        <logger name="Microsoft.*" minlevel="Info" final="true" />
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="tasksJsonFile" />
        
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a compound template to include the json layout and a simple text layout with a `,`.

Take a look at the example: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/CompoundLayout#from-xml

```
<target name='file' type='File' fileName='log.txt'>
  <layout type='CompoundLayout'>
    <layout type='SimpleLayout' text="myAmazingText: " />
    <layout type='JsonLayout'>
      <attribute name='time' layout='${longdate}' />
      <attribute name='level' layout='${level:upperCase=true}'/>
    </layout>
  </layout>
</target>
```

so for your case it would be something like:

```
<target xsi:type="File" name="tasksJsonFile" fileName="c:\\logFiles\\json-${shortdate}.log">
  <layout type='CompoundLayout'>
    <layout xsi:type="JsonLayout" includeAllProperties="false">
      <attribute name="time" layout="${longdate}" />
      <attribute name="name" layout="${callsite}" />
      <attribute name="level" layout="${level:upperCase=true}"/>
      <attribute name="message" layout="${message}" />
    </layout>
    <layout type='SimpleLayout' text="," />
  </layout>
</target>
```

Comment: Can you please improve your answer by including relevant parts of the linked content in case the link goes dead in the future?

Comment: sure copied the sample

Comment: The sample does not seem to solve the problem stated by the OP.

Comment: not sure I understand the comment here, do you want me to create a complete xml and give it to the user who asked question. I am suggesting him to take a look at the sample, the compound template example adds a simple text at the beginning of the json, he should use a similar strategy to add a comma after the json template... could you please elaborate?

Comment: here added the additional sample

Comment: I don't need to do anything else at the time. I tried it and it worked fine. Thanks